# Extend symfony task in plugin

Tags: plugins, symfony1, listener, task

I am working with a plugin in symfony 1.4, and would like to add a listener for a task from another plugin. When the user does `php symfony doctrine:build` I want my plugin to run a task of its own. Where/how do I register the listener? I did not have any success with http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/17-Extending-Symfony

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can hook your code to any symfony task. Have a look at sfBaseTask::doRun method. Any task, when is executed, emits 2 events: command.pre_command and command.post_command.

Create a class to store you code, for example:

```
class toolkitEvents
{
  static public function commandPostEventHook(sfEvent $event)
  {
    $task = $event->getSubject();
    if ($task->getFullName() === 'doctrine:build')
    { 
     //do stuff or call another task
    }
}
```

and connect this method to a dispatcher when initializing your plugin:

```
class yourPluginConfiguration extends sfPluginConfiguration
{
  public function initialize()
  {
    $this->dispatcher->connect('command.post_command', array('toolkitEvents', 'commandPostEventHook'));  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a suitable event for this (like the cache clear one).

My suggestion would be either to accept that it needs to be two tasks, or if you use build that often, create a wrapper task to call one first then the other - doctrine:build is a good example of how to do this. Or a bash/batch script!

Comment: "create a wrapper task to call one first then the other" - I think that's the solution. Thank you!